# What measurement should be used to determine per unit capacity of a given volume ish question

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, data-analysis, descriptive-statistics

I am reselling data packages and would like to add a sense of scale to the packages. Without disputing actual numbers, an email message is between (3-20)Kbytes, a photo 270kb, a web page (.25-1.5)Mbytes, 1 minute of streaming music 500kb, 1 minute streaming video (2-5)mbytes.
If I have two package (100 and 200)MB, and ranging values, what measure should I use to report for example
"the 100MB package means you can transfer 500 emails, 200 pictures (...)" etc. What is common practice? Use the median? The mode? Sanitize the data by killing outlying values?

Thanks in advance, and if I am not asking the right question, please let me know. It sounds to me like a mouthful of math!

Answer (score 0):

My intuition is to kill the outliers, and use numbers near where the normal distro goes from being concave up like to cup to to being concave down like a frown because of the large integral value of the area under the curve around thereish. Alternatively, I could be bonkers about that. Don't go easy on me!